# How to change status field automatically from 1 to 0 when end_time is reached

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is my Auction model:

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    auction_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    crop = models.ForeignKey(Crop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="crop-image")
    farmer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'user_type': 'farmer'})
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=[('kg', 'Kilograms'), ('tonne', 'Metric Tons'), ('bushel', 'Bushels'), ('crate', 'Crates')])
    hammer_price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    payment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Auctions"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.crop.title
```

When combined end_date and end_time  is reached, status which is by default set to 1 on auction creation should be changed to 0.

Comment: Why define a `status` anyway? Why not just check the `end_date`? Furthermore please *don't* separate the date and time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply *not* add a status, but check if the end timestamp is used. By defining a `status` field, you introduce *data duplication*, you specify the same thing *twice*.

You probably should also *combine* the date and the time, since a timestamp is more than a date and a time because of *daylight saving time* for example.

```
from django.conf import settings


class Auction(models.Model):
    auction_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    crop = models.ForeignKey(Crop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='crop-image')
    farmer = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'user_type': 'farmer'},
    )
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    # no status
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=[
            ('kg', 'Kilograms'),
            ('tonne', 'Metric Tons'),
            ('bushel', 'Bushels'),
            ('crate', 'Crates'),
        ],
    )
    hammer_price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    payment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Auctions'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.crop.title
```

So we can for example get all `Auction`s that are still active with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Auction.objects.filter(end_timestamp__gte=Now())
```

Now we thus determine the status in a *passive* way, which is normally more reliable than some process that actively changes it.

We can boost performance by setting a [**`db_index=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#db-index) on it.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: This can be combined with a `status` property on the model that will give the status according to the timestamp.